# How to be faster while deleting vector row?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

This is taking way too long for what I would like to do.
Any way to make this faster?

**edit** sorry I kept having a quality post code problem so I just posted the bare minimum.

What I am trying to do is a omaha poker equity calculator.

A-It takes the 4 cards we give him (myhand[4]) and it check with all the combination of possible hands to see if there is any duplicate.

B-If there is any duplicate, it wants to delete the row of the vector containing that hand
(so when we calculate equity later on, we will not calculate against a hand that is impossible for someone to have)

```
int myhand[4] = { 3, 12, 22, 10 };
    vector<vector<int> > vec(4, vector<int>(270725));
    for (int m = 0; m < vec[0].size(); m++) { // A
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                if (myhand[k] == vec[j][m]) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        vec[i].erase(vec[i].begin() + m); // B
                    }
                    k = 0;
                    j = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Is there ways to be more efficient with this code ?

thanks,
Kaven

Comment: What's the point of it all? It would be really useful to know what the code is supposed to achieve on a high level to see how it best can be optimized.

Comment: It looks weird... 4 for loops for this looks like overkill

Comment: transposing the matrix might improve performance.

Comment: 270725 is already 4 out of 52 without order. So you at least don't need 4 vec of size() = 270725 but of size() = 52. And btw - your inner vectors just hold zeros, that's not what you need.

Comment: Is this running too slow?  If not, why are we playing with it?  :)

Comment: To optimize, consider using a more appropriate data structure for hands of cards, namely instances of sets.

Comment: Consider using `deque` instead of `vector` if you're going to be making lots of inserts/deletes anywhere except at the back of the container. `deque` will still give you random access, but because it's paged internally, mutations like this are much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off constructing the combinations you want to process through a loop that looks somewhat like this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main (int, char* [])
{
    // Build a deck of cards
    std::vector<int> deck( 52 );
    std::iota( deck.begin(), deck.end(), 0 );

    // Remove 'myhand'
    const int myhand[] =  { 3, 12, 22, 10 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        deck[myhand[i]] = -1;
    }
    deck.resize( std::remove( deck.begin(), deck.end(), -1 ) - deck.begin() );

    // Iterate over all possible remaining entries.
    size_t num_processed = 0;
    for (auto c1 = deck.begin(); c1 != deck.end(); ++c1) {
        for (auto c2 = c1 + 1; c2 != deck.end(); ++c2) {
            for (auto c3 = c2 + 1; c3 != deck.end(); ++c3) {
                for (auto c4 = c3 + 1; c4 != deck.end(); ++c4) {
                    // Compute equity of (*c1, *c2, *c3, *c4) here.

                    ++num_processed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Verify that 48! / (44! * 4!) entries were processed.
    assert ( num_processed == (48*47*46*45) / (4*3*2*1) );
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, I wrote a hold'em poker equity calculator.

Comment: What I am doing is pretty much like this but I cannot generate random hands like this as I have to respect a certain ranking of hands if I want to calculate against a specific range(%) preflop. I will try to adapt this to my code. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on a non-associative container like  std::vector is too expensive.

std::set would be fine if if were just Hands to be found, but the keys in question are  composite keys (4-tuples of cards) in terms of the problem domain  and std::set has no special means to deal with with things like

"Find all keys that CONTAIN a certain component."

std::map would also only solve one part of the problem.

boost::bimap could be considered, but I propose a different approach:

---

The problem's data can be modeled by a bipartite graph (cards left, hands right, l<->r edge means "is in hand" from the "Card vertex" and "contains Card" if seen from the "Hand vertex".

Thus I would prefer using (STL-based) boost::graph over self-coded STL-based solutions.

---

The other practical approach would be relying on an in-memory database which could be easily created using SQLite; pls attend 
http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer from what i understood.

You are making `k=0` when `myhand[k] == vec[j][m]` . It breaks j for loop.

But k for loop restarts again from zero.

If it matches condition `myhand[k] == vec[j][m]` again, it keeps continuing.

Apart from this, consider using `std::find` algorithm, instead of you writing loop etc.